# Reading String from Variable for SQL Query

Tags: php, sql

SQL newb here...

`$db_result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name FROM gamers WHERE comp_id = 'myid'");` works the way I want.

```
$compid1 = 'myid';
$db_result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name FROM gamers WHERE comp_id = @compid1");
```

does not yield the same results.

I have also tried `$compid1` and various other things, but without success.

Sorry for the simple question, but the answer is still eluding me.  Thanks!

UPDATE:  Oh yea...the question.  How can I use a prestored variable for my WHERE check?

Comment: No it won't work, a MySQL variable (prefixed with `@`) isn't automagically linked with a PHP variable of the same name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$` before a variable, not `@`. And you need to put quotes around it since it's a string:

```
$db_result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name FROM gamers WHERE comp_id = '$compid1'");
```

However, it would be best if you stopped using the `mysql` extension. Use PDO or mysqli, and use prepared statements with parameters. E.g. in PDO it would be:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT first_name FROM gamers WHERE comp_id = :compid");
$stmt->bindParam(':compid', $compid1);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: thanks! if I run the PDO version, how would i grab $db_result?

Comment: You use `$stmt->fetch()` to get the results. It's all in the PDO documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the string variable inside a pair of quotes.

```sql
$compid1 = 'myid';
$db_result = mysql_query("SELECT first_name FROM gamers WHERE comp_id = '$compid1'");
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd give you a green checkmark too if I had an extra, but Barmar beat ya to it.